# Which are Scala alternatives for MDB or JMS?

Tags: scala

I am now in the process of convincing my boss to start using Scala for our web application. I shown him some nice features and frameworks (Play 2.x) where Scala power is greatly noticed and now he comes up with a question where I need some Scala expert's advices:

> what are the frameworks used in Scala for building queue based message processing (same as MDB and JMS) and what transaction management systems are used and how they compare with EJB based container managed txns ?

Because I don't have to much experience with Scala, I am pretty lost in finding documentation about this question. Can you please give me some suggestions?

Comment: As for the first one -- you may take a [look at apache kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/), which is not only used in scala, but is written in scala (internal code isn't much idiomatic though). We're running Storm + Kafka + Cassandra event sourced system and overall experience is pretty good. P.S. frankly speaking, it's kinda risky trying to convince your coworkers into scala if you don't have much experience in the language -- possible major issues which you may fail to resolve may distract them from scala entirely

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have about 1yr experience working for some projects in my free time but I haven't experience exactly in this area:)... Hope I can convince them...:)